# Animate not working properly/only activating after first hover

Tags: jquery, css

EDIT: Here is a working fiddle without the modernizr fallback .no-csstransition:
http://jsfiddle.net/xTT5s/12/ (I removed the css3 easing effect to avoid conflict on moz/chrome)

First of all Im not so used to jQuery, so this could be a pretty dumb thing at all.

Well, Im working on a jQuery .hover .animate for a CSS3 transition (easing) fallback for the IEs. Here is the code of the CSS/Jquery fallback:

NOTE: (The .no-csstransitions is the modernizr fallback for css3 selectors)

```
    section figure {
    width: 220px; height: 220px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;        
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 40px 40px 0;
}

    section figure figcaption {
    width: 220px; height: 57px;
    background: #474747;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px 0 0 10px;
    top: 221px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out; 
            transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
section figure:hover figcaption {
    margin-top: -63px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out; 
            transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".no-csstransitions figure").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('figcaption', this).stop(true, true).animate({top: "221px"}, 300);;
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('figcaption', this).animate({top: "250px"}, 300);;
    }
});
});
```

1º The animate is triggering only after the first .hover

2º .hover animate effect only happens when i set the top position to MAX 219, if I place 220 the effect doesnt trigger, Im not sure why.

3º The .mouseleave effect happens only after a while, the figcaption blinks to a certain position then the easing happens...

This is a preview version of my wip: http://fernandofleury.com.br/preview/portfolio/

I will remove the overflow: hidden; so you guys can see it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try it more like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/WpyUf/10/), as you're mixing apple's and orange's a little with both hover and mouseleave.

Comment: Thank you for improving the code @adeno! Makes more sense playing over that function. I will update the code. But the 3 problems still remains the same.

Comment: You should try to replicate the problem in a jsFiddle, and post the fiddle in your question, that way it's easier for people to see what the problem is, and help you!

Comment: I think the `margin-top:-63px` on :hover is what is making the `.figcaption` jump, or blink. For the position, you could try to use the relative animate position, to avoid having to calculate the relevant position: http://jsfiddle.net/xTT5s/14/

Comment: Indeed froddd. This solved all of the problems I had. Can you post this as answer so I can vote up?